# How to update database for the checkbox selected id's and send mail to respective email addresses

Tags: php, mysql, email, checkbox

I want to send welcome mail to all users whose id gets status 1. I have achieved setting status 1 to those users who are being selected via checkbox but can't figure out how to send email to all who are checked. A suggestion would be helpful.

Here is my code for the same, do let me know what else I need to add for taking 'email' into variable '$check' and send mail.

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="all_check[]" <?php echo $disabled ;?> value= "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"class="checkbox" id="status" ></td>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="user_id" id="user_id" >
```

And, code where I am setting status=1 for the selected users,

```
                <?php
if(!empty($_POST['all_check'])) {
    foreach($_POST['all_check'] as $check) {
          $update_status= mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_user SET status = '1' WHERE id = $check" );  
  }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of error you are facing?

Comment: @NisargDesai Thanks for concern. I am executing this above written code successfully but all I want to know how to get corresponding 'email' from database against the id in '$check' variable. Basically I need id(which I am getting) and email too into '$check'.

Comment: you can not execute select and update query at the same time. there are two way 1. you can  write select query and store that fetch data into one variable and pass that into next query. 2 you can create trigger on update statement on that tbl_user and pass same update query into mysql_fetch_array and fetch data from them.

Comment: @NisargDesai I got your point. But what the scenario is, here admin is selecting users to approve through checkboxes and that approval is being done by updating the status field. Now what I want is  to send a welcome email to the selected users after approving them. So as I am updating the status on by fetching the id, how can I send mail to the checked and approved users. My phpmailer is working but I need to have emails

Answer (score 0):

Here look at the code may it will be give you some Idea.

```
if(!empty($_POST['all_check'])) {
    foreach($_POST['all_check'] as $check) {
    $update_status= mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_user SET status = '1' WHERE id = $check" );  
     $query=mysql_query("Select email From tbl_user where WHERE id=$check");
     if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
     mail( $row['email'],"Welcome ","Welcome Message");
     }
  }
```

like this you have to pass two different query for updating and selecting operations.

Comment: Thanks for this Nisarg. But may I know "if(mysql)" stands for what?